# Union of values of two dictionaries merged by key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'a':('x','y'),'b':('k','l')}
d2 = {'a':('m','n'),'c':('p','r')}
```

How do I merge these two dictionaries to get such result:

```
d3 = {'a':('x','y','m','n'),'b':('k','l'),'c':('p','r')}
```

This works when values of the dictionary are simple type like int or str:

```
d3 = dict([(i,a[i]+b[i]) for i in set(a.keys()+b.keys())])
```

But I have no idea how deal with lists as values...

Notice: my question is different to [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) cause I don't want to update values but add them

Comment: Possible duplicate. This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Comment: @gargas I don't think it's a duplicate. The question you referenced is a last-one-wins, not a value merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little bit mangled with respect to variable names, but I think this does what you want:

```
d3 = dict([(i,d1.get(i,())+d2.get(i,())) for i in set(d1.keys()+d2.keys())])
d3
{'a': ('x', 'y', 'm', 'n'), 'b': ('k', 'l'), 'c': ('p', 'r')}
```

Note that you can add (ie extend) `list`s and `tuples` with `+`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with adding lists in Python (it concatenates them); there's a bit of a problem deciding when to add, though, as it should be done only when the key appears in both dictionaries.

```
d3 = dict(
    [(i, d1[i]+d2[i]) for i in set(d1.keys()).intersection(d2.keys())] +\
    [(i, d1[i]) for i in set(d1.keys()) - set(d2.keys())] +\
    [(i, d2[i]) for i in set(d2.keys()) - set(d1.keys())])
>> d3
{'a': ('x', 'y', 'm', 'n'), 'b': ('k', 'l'), 'c': ('p', 'r')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You **can** just add lists and tuples, that should work.

   `In [5]: ('x','y') + ('m','n')`

   `Out[5]: ('x', 'y', 'm', 'n')`
2. `d3 = dict([(i,a[i]+b[i]) for i in set(a.keys()+b.keys())])` fails in any case where a key only shows up in `a` or `b` but not both. Values are irrelevant here.

Personally, I'd go with something like:

```
d3 = {}

for i in set(a.keys()+b.keys()):
    val1 = a[i] if i in a else ()
    val2 = b[i] if i in b else ()
    d3[i] = val1+val2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use dict.viewitems with a for loop:

```
d1 = {'a': ('x', 'y'), 'b': ('k', 'l')}
d2 = {'a': ('m', 'n'), 'c': ('p', 'r')}

d3 = {}

for key, item in d1.viewitems() | d2.viewitems():
    d3[key]= d3.get(key,()) + item

print(d3)

{'a': ('x', 'y', 'm', 'n'), 'c': ('p', 'r'), 'b': ('k', 'l')}
```

Or use  a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d3 = defaultdict(tuple)
for key, item in d1.viewitems() | d2.viewitems():
    d3[key] += item

print(d3)
```

Or use viewkeys for your lists as they are not hashable:

```
d1 = {'a': ['x', 'y'], 'b': ['k', 'l']}
d2 = {'a': ['m', 'n'], 'c': ['p', 'r']}


d3 = {}

for key in d1.viewkeys() | d2.viewkeys():
    d3[key] = d1.get(key, []) + d2.get(key, [])

print(d3)
```

Which you can write as a dict comp:

```
d3 = {key:d1.get(key, []) + d2.get(key, []) for key in  d1.viewkeys() | d2.viewkeys()}
```

for lists you could also  chain the items:

```
d1 = {'a': ['x', 'y'], 'b': ['k', 'l']}
d2 = {'a': ['m', 'n'], 'c': ['p', 'r']}


from collections import defaultdict
d3 = defaultdict(list)
from itertools import chain
for key, v in chain.from_iterable((d1.items(),d2.items())):
    d3[key] += v

print(d3)

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['x', 'y', 'm', 'n'], 'c': ['p', 'r'], 'b': ['k', 'l']})
```

For python3 just use `.items` and `.keys` as they return dictview objects.