# Merge values of two Python dictionaries by keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to merge the values of two dictionaries by their keys. Example:

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
d2 = {'a':2, 'b':[2,3], 'd':3}
```

desired output:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 2, 3], 'c': [3], 'd': [3]}
```

What I have so far is

```
d12 = {}
for d in (d1, d2):
    for k,v in d.items(): 
        d12.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

which produces

```
d12 = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, [2, 3]], 'c': [3], 'd': [3]}
```

not desired output.

I searched a bit on SO and found that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093734/7864386) answers my question if only it didn't throw up `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your values are sometimes `int`s and sometimes `list`s. You must check the data type and either `append` or `extend` accordingly:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        d12.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
    else:
        d12.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using `dict.update` with a `lambda` flatten function and `dict.get`:

```
dct = {}
for i in d1.keys() | d2.keys():
    flatten = lambda *n: [e for a in n for e in (flatten(*a) if isinstance(a, (tuple, list)) else (a,))]
    l = flatten([i for i in [d1.get(i, None), d2.get(i, None)] if i])
    dct.update({i: l})
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'b': [2, 2, 3], 'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'd': [3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only using `append`,

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
d2 = {'a':2, 'b':[2,3], 'd':3}

d12 = {}
for d in (d1, d2):
    for k,v in d.items(): 
        if not isinstance(v, list):
            d12.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
        else:
            for i in v:
                d12.setdefault(k, []).append(i)


print(d12)
```